# My data-attribute is empty if i try to store too much data inside it

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, x-editable

i have a problem with the new implementet JSON storage in MySQL.
I am using mysql-5.7.12, jquery-2.1.1 and bootstrap-editable-1.5.1

The code looks like this:

```
<dt>Memo</dt>
foreach(json_decode($row['memo'], true) as $user => $memo) {
    // $row['memo'] is something like: {"user":"very-long-text-with-some\\n escaped lines..."}
    echo "
    <dd><a class='memo' id='telephone-memo' data-pid='".$row['id']."' data-text='".$memo."' employee='".$user."'>new</a></dd>";
}
```

The `a class='memo' ...` is the x-editable.

A look inside the database shows no error. I can store more than enough inside the JSON string.

The problem is if i store more than 194 chars in the x-editable textarea, the data-text attribute shows empty! If this accures the user will overwrite his data with the next edit, because he/she did'nt see the actual stored data. Is there a limitation i did'nt know from?

I am exceedingly grateful for your help.

Comment: *"Is there a limitation"* no. Try using `data-text='".json_encode($memo)."'` since `json_decode()` will remove escaping

Comment: Fred: in mysql there is no column-length defined, type is json.
charlietfl: Gread idea, i will try this now!

Comment: The solution `data-text='".json_encode($memo)."'` does not work too.
The output is: `<dd><a class='memo' id='telephone-memo' data-pid='401410' data-text='' employee=''>neu</a></dd>`

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is solved!

I'm using since many years a UCFIRST() function in MySQL.
This is a 8-bit function!!
Normally used for names ect.

Function for the JSON-column removed and it works.